# Current flow in potentiometers

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, voltage, electronics

In the following circuit involving a potentiometer;

[image]

Assume $V$ to be the voltage produced by the cell in the primary circuit across the length $AJ$ of the potentiometer wire, and $E$ to be that produced by the cell of the secondary circuit.

In the case of $V=E$, it's known that there is zero current through the secondary circuit. The current would obviously follow the path of the potential drop and not the rise, but in this limiting case, why is there current flow through the potentiometer wire instead of the secondary circuit, when the potential drops are similar in both?

Comment: How did you conclude that "the net potential difference between A and J is zero"?

Comment: Isn't the potential calculated by the scalar sum?

Comment: As you mentioned in the question, potential difference across AJ is V=E and not 0.

Comment: Oh, right. So current flows through the path that has the potential **drop**, and not the rise, right?

Comment: Yes, you got it.

Comment: Sorry, the question phrasing was abysmal; I've modified it now.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

As potential difference between points $A$ and $B$as well as $J$ and $C$ is zero, there is no current in the secondary circuit. However, there is current in the primary circuit due to the primary (known) cell.